# How do I tell IE to add the class 'Selected' to my LI on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was hoping to get a little help with my code. This works in moz/webkit but not in ie. I don't quite understand why :(

```
$(window).trigger('hashchange');

// Add .selected class to nav on page scroll
var $sections = $('section');  
var $navs = $('nav > ul > li');
var topsArray = $sections.map(function() {
    return $(this).position().top - 50;  
}).get();                              
var len = topsArray.length;  
var currentIndex = 0;        
var getCurrent = function( top ) {   
    for( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {   
        if( top > topsArray[i] && topsArray[i+1] && top < topsArray[i+1] ) {
            return i;

        }
    }
};

$(document).scroll(function(e) {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    var secondSection = topsArray[1];

    if(scrollTop <= 200) { // moved past the header
        $navs.eq(0).removeClass("selected")
    } else if(scrollTop >= 205 && scrollTop <= secondSection ) { // between header and 2nd section
        $navs.eq(0).addClass("selected")
    } 
    var checkIndex = getCurrent( scrollTop );
        if( checkIndex !== currentIndex ) {
            currentIndex = checkIndex;
            $navs.eq( currentIndex ).addClass("selected").siblings(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

IE is not very forgiving of javascript errors. Try adding some missing semicolons:

```
if(scrollTop <= 200) { // moved past the header
    $navs.eq(0).removeClass("selected"); //missing semicolon
} else if(scrollTop >= 205 && scrollTop <= secondSection ) { // between header and 2nd section
    $navs.eq(0).addClass("selected"); //missing semicolon
}
```

If it is IE only, then IE is having trouble parsing the js. Try running your js through a debugger like [JsLint](http://www.jslint.com/) if you run into issues.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It's been a while since I've worked with JS and forgot about lint. Should have gone there first.

The problem wasn't with the semicolons though, it was the method I was using for tracking the window scroll. I should have used $(window).scroll instead of $(document).